# How to get event node to pull in data from a seperate node?

Tags: 6, nodes

I'm trying to setup an events calendar in drupal 6. I have an event content type and a location content type. My problem is that I want the event node to display relevant data from the location node such as location name, address, hours, etc.. I'm not sure of the best way to set this up?

Additional info: My event content type has a cck node reference that points to the location node. I was looking at the reverse node reference module but wasn't sure if that was necessary, maybe this can be accomplished using existing views and block functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from you question you want to know the best way to display some information from the location inside the event node view page, if this the case you might need to create a  block view (from views module) takes the reference node location (nid) in the current node event being viewed, and as you have the view you can display all the information needed.

I hope this will help.

Comment: I actually have it set up this way now but the node reference only passes in the location node title. I need to figure out how to pass in the nid instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to edit the formatter on the manage display tab. Instead of the default formatter, which is something like link to referenced node, change it to use the rendered node

Comment: I need to double check but doesn't that bring in the entire node? Is there a way to just get the nid?

Comment: Yes, there are a couple of ways. One way would be to use a block as it sounds like you are doing below. Another way would be to use the entity views attachment module. And you could also use tokens to create a custom display and use that formatter when pulling in the rendered node

Comment: entity views attachment seems to be drupal7 only